# When applying to a second master’s degree , can my first master compensate a low undergraduate GPA?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, computer-science, undergraduate, gpa

I have a 3.31/5 GPA in mechanical engineering undergrad but got work as a software engineer, 4 years have passed since then, i have had promotions in my work as programmer and I also Will graduate in the next months from my first master degree in software engineering with a 4,6/5 GPA.I want to pursuit a second master degree in computer science, can my undergrad affect me from getting accepted?

Comment: yes it can compensate but at around the 5th master's degree it stops working.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to predict with certainty as systems differ, but it seems unlikely. Your most recent degree normally ranks higher in the calculations and it is closer to the new field.

But I wonder why you want a second masters. There will be a fair amount of overlap. That, alone, might count against you if people in the decision process think the slot might better go to someone else. That might depend a lot on country, though. Make sure you can justify this in any application.